# Async handler failing in jest (React) on unhandledRejection

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jasmine, jestjs, puppeteer

Following e2e test throws the following error:

`Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified byjasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.`

```
 // describe the test
describe('Login Component Tests',
  () => {
         const handleSubmit = jest.fn();

         let browser;
         let page;

         beforeAll(async () => {
             browser = await puppeteer.launch({
                 headless: false,
             });
             page = await browser.newPage();
         }); // timeout

         afterAll(() => {
             browser = browser.close();
         });

         // handler submits
         it('has a handler that submits', async (done) => {
             await page.goto('http://localhost:3000/login');
             page.emulate({
                 viewport: {
                     width: 1000,
                     height: 800,
                 },
                 userAgent: '',
             });

             await page.waitForSelector('.login-form');

             await page.type('input[name=email]', 'username');
             await page.type('input[name=password]', 'password');
             await page.click('button[type=submit]');

             const error = await page.waitForSelector('.ant-message-notice');
             expect(error).not.toBe('object');
         });
     },
     10000,
 );
```

The headless chrome loads the login page and logs in with the credentials as well but the error still comes up.

I have tried setting the interval inside `describe` block and it still fails. Not sure what is wrong here with jest.

Comment: What is the mount doing? And you don't need an async at the top describe handler.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to use enzyme and puppeteer together... Are you trying to do full browser-with-network testing (puppeteer `page.goto`) or not (enzyme)? The two approaches are not very compatible.

Comment: @Mrchief: mount is being used for another test.

Comment: @WillCain: Yes, both are being used. I will look into compatibility issues about the two, thanks.

Comment: ah, gotcha @NegativeSpark, separate tests, that's definitely understandable; you might consider removing the enzyme part from your question entirely to keep it clear and focused

Comment: @Mrchief: Removing the async from the top gives me this error now:     Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 10000ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.